# Zenbook UX305 disconnecting wifi in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless, connection

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on an ASUS Zenbook UX305 and cannot use the wifi.

The LAN works over the Ethernet connection, but the wifi keeps disconnecting.  I've tried to use a static IP and I've also tried using `wicd` network manager to replace the default one.  I've also looked around on AskUbuntu and tried other solutions, but nothing seems to help me enable wifi.

Before upgrading to 18.04, my wifi was working fine.  I am running out of ideas and think I should consider installing Linux Mint and see if that helps me get my wifi working.  Are there any other things I could try?

Comment: `journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager` will show you log messages. They may contain hints. Taking a BIG STEP (installing some other distribution) to fix a small problem is unwise. What other "problems" come with The Other?

Comment: thanks, shall I post the results here? Do not really understand the results myself...

Comment: No. Posting logvomit is discouraged. Try to understand 1 line at a time. Some are information, some are warnings, some are Errors.

Answer (score 0):

For myself, I noticed my user had dropped out of the `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<SSID>` file.

I had to add

```
permissions=user:<username>:;
```

to the connection properties.